# Android simple random number generator crashes when EditTexts are empty

Tags: android

Long story short, my basic app has just a textview, 2x edittexts(for minimum, maximum values of random number) and a button. If minimum and maximum values are submitted everything is okay, but when i leave empty app crashes (well of course its supposed to crash), but when i tried adding some if's to avoid this, but it didn't help really.
My code fragment where the crash supposed to happen:

```
int minimumValue = 1;
int maximumValue = 2;
int randomValue = 3;
if(!minimum.getText().toString().equals("")) {
minimumValue = Integer.parseInt(minimum.getText().toString());
}
if(maximum.getText().toString().equals("")) {
maximumValue = Integer.parseInt(maximum.getText().toString());
}
randomValue = minimumValue + (int)(Math.random() * ((maximumValue - minimumValue) + 1));            
textview.setText("" + randomValue);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont check with empty String..there may be chance for entering more spaces which results you to throw `Exception`.

There is a chance of getting `NumberFormatException` too when the data is not number..

so Chage your code like this and try

```
    if (minimum.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
        try {
            minimumValue = Integer.parseInt(minimum.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }
    }
    if (maximum.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
        try {
            maximumValue = Integer.parseInt(maximum.getText().toString());

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing "!" here:

```
//if empty
if(maximum.getText().toString().equals("")) {
      \\parse empty
      maximumValue = Integer.parseInt(maximum.getText().toString());
}
```

Try with:

```
\\if empty
if(!maximum.getText().toString().equals("")) {
     maximumValue = Integer.parseInt(maximum.getText().toString());
}
```